# change row color of jquery datatable if row is checked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datatable

I have a jquery dataTable ([this is link](http://www.datatables.net/)) in each row there are a checkbox! I whish that when the checkbox is checked the row color change!

I try in this way:
tableCode;

```
<table id="tabellaOrdinaFarmaci" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Codice Farmaco</th>
            <th>Nome Farmaco</th>
            <th>Quantità</th>
            <th>Quantità di alert</th>
            <th>Stato</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <?php foreach ($query as $row): ?>
        <tr> 
            <td><?php echo $row->aic; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row->denominazione ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row->quantita; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row->alert; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row->stato; ?></td>
            <td>  <input type="checkbox" name="radiog_lite" id="<?php echo $row->aic; ?>" class="css-checkbox" />
                <label for="<?php echo $row->aic; ?>" class="css-label"></label>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</tbody>
```

jQuery code:

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('input').click(function() {
        jQuery(this).parents("tr").css('background-color', 'yellow');
    });

});
```

This code color only the rows that have an index odd!If I inspect the element from the browser `background-color: yellow` is added to all rows! Help me thanks in advance!
I think that the problem is bootstrap dataTable.

Comment: try singular parent instead of parents maybe?

Comment: try `.closest('tr')`. Also post your rendered HTML

Comment: Works fine http://jsfiddle.net/xLMm2/ btw you have two `</thead>`

Comment: I have bootstrap dataTable and don't work fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want only that row to change color for which checkbox is checked then you have to use **[closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)** and use **[change](http://api.jquery.com/change/)** event for it:

```
jQuery('#tabellaOrdinaFarmaci input:checkbox').change(function() {
       if(this.checked)  // check if checkbox checked then change color of row
          jQuery(this).closest("tr").css('background-color', 'yellow !important');
    });
```

Comment: edited answer don't work does not work either for the odd rows

Comment: I would that color every selected row!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56365/discussion-between-ermanno-tedeschi-and-ehsan-sajjad).

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery('#tabellaOrdinaFarmaci input:checkbox').change(function() {

       if(this.checked)  // check if checkbox checked then change color of row

          jQuery(this).closest("tr").css('background-color', 'yellow !important');

    });
```

`convert angulerjs`

Answer (score 0):

Use `closest()` to find the parent `<tr>`

Your elements are getting appended later to the DOM, use **[event delegation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1687296/3639582)**,

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(document).on('click','input',function() {
        jQuery(this).closest("tr").css('background-color', 'yellow');
    });

});
```